# Curl file upload from one project folder to another project folder is not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to upload from one project folder to another project folder using CURL , but its not working . Can anyone suggest me ?

Below I am posting   my codes

This code is in one project folder .

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding='multipart/form-data' method='post' action="form.php">
  <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" value="choose">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?
//echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES['uploadedfile']);
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) && $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']!="") {
 $filename  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
 $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
 $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
 $POST_DATA = array(
   'file' => base64_encode($data)
 );
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/curl_image_server/handle.php');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close ($curl);
 echo "<h2>File Uploaded</h2>";
}
?>
```

This code is in another project folder

```html
<?php
echo $encoded_file = $_POST['file'];
$decoded_file = base64_decode($encoded_file);
/* Now you can copy the uploaded file to your server. */
file_put_contents('subins', $decoded_file);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are calling `exit()` at the end of this line:

```php
echo $encoded_file = $_POST['file'];exit;
```

so the scripts end on this line, hence no file is saved.

Comment: That one I used for testing purpose,but still not working

Comment: Is the target for _file_put_contents_ writable? Have you enabled error_reporting, i.e. are you suppressing any notices or warnings? Have you checked server log?